# Get value inside Div Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

ho,

I have a div that I access like so:

```
 var gridcellrowvalue0 = gridcell0.innerHTML;
```

This returns to me the following div:

```
 <div class="DivOverflowNoWrap Ellipsis" style="width:100%;" data-textwidth="50" data-originaltext="DefaultText" data-ingrid="1">DefaultText</div>
```

In my JS I would like to accesss the `"DefaultText"` variable and I have tried this:

```
 gridcellrowvalue0.innerHTML;
 gridcellrowvalue0.getAttribute("data-originaltext");
```

But none of them work. I'm assuming that getAttribute doesn't work because it is not really an element, it's innerhtml.

My goal is to use the `"DefaultText"` value in an IF-statement and therefore I simply need it.

I appreciate any pointers, my friends!

Comment: Why are you getting the innerHTML of innerHTML?

Comment: Just set an ID for the div Element, then you can easily access it via:


 `var gridcellrowvalue0=document.getElementById("your_div_id").innerHTML `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could access your element directly from `gridcell0` using  `gridcell0.querySelector('.DivOverflowNoWrap')` instead, like :

```
var gridcell0 = document.querySelector('#x');
console.log( gridcell0.querySelector('.DivOverflowNoWrap').innerHTML );
```

Snippet:

```js
var gridcell0 = document.querySelector('#x');

if (gridcell0.querySelector('.DivOverflowNoWrap') !== null) {
  console.log(gridcell0.querySelector('.DivOverflowNoWrap').innerHTML);
} else {
  console.log('Does not exist');
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <div class="DivOverflowNoWrap Ellipsis" style="width:100%;" data-textwidth="50" data-originaltext="DefaultText" data-ingrid="1">DefaultText</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can check for nulls elegantly? I tried this: if(gridcell0.querySelector('.DivOverflowNoWrap') != null) but this throws an exception if it indeed is null, even when I am checking for null.

Comment: This unfortunately has the same issue I am having. :( when I run that, it breaks the code at runtime on the if(gridcell0.querySelector('.DivOverflowNoWrap') !== null) line. Says it can't run querySelector on null (even if it is simply checking for it).

Comment: aaah then you've to check `gridcell0` first `if( gridcell0 !== null )`. ..

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript also it can be achieved but I am showing here using **jQuery**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var div = $(".DivOverflowNoWrap");
  var text = div.text();

  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DivOverflowNoWrap Ellipsis" style="width:100%;" data-textwidth="50" data-originaltext="DefaultText" data-ingrid="1">DefaultText</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you access the div in the first place. If you do it like you described (with `gridcell0.innerHTML`). It will return a string. Not an HTML element.

Therefore you can't use `.getAttribute` or `.innerHTML`, because you  try to apply it on a string. Access your div differently (`querySelector` or `getElementBy...`) and you will be able to use those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery:

```
$("[class='DivOverflowNoWrap']").text();


$("[class='DivOverflowNoWrap']").attr("data-originaltext")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```html
<html><head></head>
<div class="DivOverflowNoWrap Ellipsis" style="width:100%;" data-textwidth="50" data-originaltext="DefaultText" data-ingrid="1">DefaultText</div>
<script>
test();
function test(){
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("DivOverflowNoWrap Ellipsis")[0].getAttribute("data-originaltext");
alert(x);
}
</script>
</html>
```